# How can I find when a user was last active using discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm using the discord.py library and want to purge inactive members by kicking them from the server. I am aware of the function [discord.Guild.prune_members](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.prune_members), however it does not provide all the functionality I need as I'd like to send the user a warning a few days before they are removed.

How can I best find when a user was last active so that I can calculate the number of days they have been inactive for? I have been searching the internet for several days and cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [discord.py](https://discord.gg/r3sSKJJ) server, you can use a simple cache alongside a database to keep track of this. Let's run through a simple example on how we could do this.

```py
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, Dict, List

import discord
from discord.ext import commands

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    import datetime
    import asyncpg
    
    # We set the type checking here to avoid errors, your bot instance
    # shouldnt run into this issue and this shouldnt be needed.
    class Bot(commands.Bot):
        pool: asyncpg.Pool[asyncpg.Record]
else:
    Bot = commands.Bot
        

# We're going to layout our data as so:
# CREATE TABLE prune (member_id BIGINT, guild_id BIGINT, last_login TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE)

class Tracker(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot: Bot) -> None:
        self.bot: Bot = bot
        
        self.presence_cache: Dict[int, Dict[int, datetime.datetime]] = {} # mapping of guild : {member_id: last_login}
    
    async def cog_load(self) -> None:
        # Let's load the info from our database table into our cache.
        # This implements a postgres asyncpg pool
        data = await self.bot.pool.fetch('SELECT * FROM prune') # type: ignore
        for entry in data:
            entry: asyncpg.Record
            
            # Enter in the guild id and the member id
            if (guild_id := entry['guild_id']) not in self.presence_cache:
                self.presence_cache[guild_id] = {}

            self.presence_cache[guild_id][entry['member_id']] = entry['last_login']
            
    async def cog_unload(self) -> None:
        # We need to dump back into our database here, so we can save our data.
        async with self.bot.pool.acquire() as connection:
            async with connection.transaction():
                query = 'INSERT INTO prune (member_id, guild_id, last_login) VALUES ($1, $2, $3) ON CONFLICT (member_id, guild_id) DO UPDATE SET last_login = $3'
                
                # Let's format our data so we can use executemany
                # The formatted data should be a list of tuples, (member_id, guild_id, last_login)
                formatted_data = [(member_id, guild_id, last_login) for guild_id, guild_data in self.presence_cache.items() for member_id, last_login in guild_data.items()]
                await connection.executemany(query, formatted_data)
    
    @commands.Cog.listener('on_presence_update')
    async def on_presence_update(self, before: discord.Member, after: discord.Member) -> None:
        if before.status == after.status: # The two statuses are the same, return
            return
        
        if not (before.status is discord.Status.offline and after.status is discord.Status.online): # The member did NOT come onine
            return
        
        # This means the member's last login was just now, let's add it to our cache to update
        if (guild_id := after.guild.id) not in self.presence_cache:
            self.presence_cache[guild_id] = {}
        
        self.presence_cache[guild_id][after.id] = discord.utils.utcnow() # utc now (dpy is timezone aware in 2.0)
        
    @commands.command(
        name='get_prune',
        brief='Get the members who will be pruned',
        description='Get the members who will be pruned',
    )
    @commands.guild_only()
    async def get_prune(self, ctx: commands.Context[Bot], days: int) -> None:
        assert ctx.guild is not None
        
        # Let's find the members who would be pruned
        query = 'SELECT member_id FROM prune WHERE guild_id = $1 AND last_login < $2'
        data = await self.bot.pool.fetch(query, ctx.guild.id, (discord.utils.utcnow() - datetime.timedelta(days=days)).replace(tzinfo=None)) 
        
        # Now let's format an embed
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title=f'{len(data)} members will be pruned',
        )
        
        members: List[discord.Member] = []
        for entry in data:
            member = ctx.guild.get_member(entry['member_id']) or (await ctx.guild.fetch_member(entry['member_id']))
            members.append(member)
            
        embed.description = ', '.join(member.mention for member in members)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, allowed_mentions=discord.AllowedMentions.none())
```

In this example, we used the async `cog_load` and `cog_unload` functions to keep a cache up to date. To append to our cache we used `on_presence_update` to check when the member came online. I've also implemented a simple command to get the members who would be pruned after X days. It can be invoked as so:

`[pr]get_prune 20`

If you have any questions feel free to reach out on this thread :)